# How do I perform a click on several buttons in sequence?

Tags: c#, button, events, click, sequence

I have 4 buttons that will reproduce a sound (each one of them) when activated, but I want to "activate" those 4 buttons, one right after the other (in order o sequence), by clicking on another single button, let's say `button10`.

Example:

```cs
private void button10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      button1.PerformClick();
      button2.PerformClick();
      button3.PerformClick();
      button4.PerformClick();
}
```

No need to pass any time between the clicking of the buttons, it just needs to happen one after the other, and in order.

Answer (score 1):

Your example should already be working. Having trouble sorting?

```
private void button10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      button1.PerformClick();
      button2.PerformClick();
      button3.PerformClick();
      button4.PerformClick();
}
```

Comment: If you're having trouble with the ordering, could you try adding a `Task.Delay(durationOfYourSound);` after each `button.PerformClick();` method?

Comment: every button is working on its own, playing a sound as they should be, but when i click in the main button, the one that is supposed to performclick on the other 4, and play them in sequence, only the first one is clicked and reproduce the sound, the other 3 don't appear to be attached in the code, Is not necessary for me to have a time delay between clicking, just need them to perform click right after the other. Also i just tried Task.Delay, but didn't work

Comment: Can you share the codes of the main button and one of the other four buttons?

Comment: private void button10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
            button1.PerformClick();
            button2.PerformClick();
            button3.PerformClick();
            button4.PerformClick();
}
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
if(comboBox10.SelectedItem.ToString() =="i")
{
 if (bgPlaying == true)
{
  notaX.Stop();

  notaX.Stop();
  bgPlaying = false;
}
 else
{
 notaX = new SoundPlayer(@"Cm.wav");
 notaX.Play();
}
}            //I shortened it to just "button1" but you can get the idea

Comment: I think the problem is due to the **if conditions**. If you haven't tested it in **debug mode**, I recommend it.

I need all the relevant parts of the code to detect that there is a problem with the **if conditions**.

Answer (score 0):

You have probably registered handlers for those buttons' clicks, so you have methods like `button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)`, etc., so you can invoke those methods directly:

```
private void button10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    button1_Click(null, null); // or pass current sender and event args
    // etc.
}
```

Comment: private void button10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            button1_Click(null, null);
            button2_Click(null, null);
            button3_Click(null, null);
            button4_Click(null, null);

        }
        It Only 'Clicks' on the first one "button1", and the rest do not work in sequence or play after the other, wich is what i want to happen on the same Event